# Dynamically imported JSON file content included in main bundle

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, ngx-translate, dynamic-import

I'm using Angular. For loading translation JSON files, I use dynamic imports. Eg.,

```
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class CustomTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  getTranslation(path: string): Observable<any> {
    return from(import(`src/assets/i18n/${path}.json`));
  }
}
```

During build, separate chunks/files are generated for each file, but I see that the content of all the files are included in the **main** bundle too and the files are not retrieved on runtime.

Comment: If you want this done runtime you can’t use import. You’ll have to fetch them (using HttpClient?)

Comment: So dynamic imports aren't meant for retrieval over HTTP?

Comment: Not really no. Imports are parsed build time.

Comment: Doesn’t mean you can’t use imports runtime, you can to dynamically load components for example.

Comment: What's the difference? Why is it that components can be loaded on runtime but not my case?

Comment: Maybe I’m not seeing the whole picture here. Can you show more of the implementation?

Comment: The code posted above is the crux. I have a `TranslationLoader`; instead of using HTTP, I tried using dynamic import there.

Comment: But.. you’re doing a .then after that..? i’m missing context here?

Comment: Edited the question to add full code

Comment: Right. So this is functional? The only issue is that it includes it in the main chunk still? Webpack is a strange beast, I’m not sure if I have anything useful to add I’m afraid. Sorry.